# How to remove a value from

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `asp_correct`. I want to count the unique items from the column `Predicted` in the dataframe. I am using the following code:

```
correct_tokens = asp_correct['Predicted'].value_counts()
correct_tokens[:20].plot.bar()
```

The output is:
[image]

However, I want to visualize all items except O.. How I could do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not zero , just very small value compared with 35000 +

Comment: Actually it is O not zero.. I want to display only the results for B_A and I_A ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `drop`

```
correct_tokens = correct_tokens.drop('O')
```

Answer (score 2):

`correct_tokens` is a Series.

Could you try `correct_tokens = correct_tokens.drop(labels=['O'])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe removing O value :

```py
     
   correct_tokens = asp_correct[asp_correct['Predicted'] != 'O']['Predicted'].value_counts()
```